# Audio signal signal processing for background noise reduction or removal

Tags: preprocessing, nlp, audio-recognition

I am performing [simple audio recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition) using tensor-flow to spot key word or hot word detection. The graph takes the **microphone input directly** and performs "Audio spectrometer --> mfcc's --> and input to the neural network."

Now i would to like to perform some kind of real time back ground noise reduction or cancellation before inputting the mfcc's into the neural network.

I am not sure what kind of algorithms/python packages that are helpful to reduce the back ground noise and If some one can point me to the pieces of code/knowledge base that can help to filter the mfcc's before inputting into neural network.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A good classifier is robust against noise. In fact, I would go the other way - use data augmentation to inject noise and train also on noisy samples. This will typically help the classifier become more robust against noise